# Cannot execute test when it is redirected to another application

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

It shows an error in the URL when an application is redirected to another application with an authentication token in the URL.

I have an application that is redirected to another application when a menu item is clicked. The second application is loaded within the primary GUI. When a user clicks the menu item, it accesses the second application with an access token in the URL.

The following is displayed in the address bar of the browser
`http://192.168.1.102:65486/IcH97oB0G*czEtTUt9m/about:error`

The URL looks like following when the menu item is clicked manually

```
https://<<my-domain>>/<<ProductName>>/?ngToken=eyJh.....hZ8PM&type=newapp&appcode=Test
```

NOTE : Also it is not possible to record the flow with the TestCafe studio too. Similar error is displayed in the address bar.

Comment: More information is required to find out the cause. Please share a minimal working example. If you don't want to share it here, you can do it in the [team repository](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A%20bug&template=bug_report.yaml).

Comment: @Aleksey sample is shared through the team repository